# Implement paint-timing in laravel

Tags: laravel, performance, browser, page-load-time

I want to implement [paint timing](https://github.com/w3c/paint-timing) steps in my website but I couldn't find any working code in internet

the only example is this in documentation every where.

```
var observer = new PerformanceObserver(function(list) {
  var perfEntries = list.getEntries();
  for (var i = 0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
     // Process entries
     // report back for analytics and monitoring
     // ...
  }
});

// register observer for paint timing notifications
observer.observe({entryTypes: ["paint"]});
```

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver)

I am using `Laravel Blade` for my website. How can I use this system in `Blade`?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like that, or instead of just console.log the values do something diffrent with them.

```
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
        if (entry.name == "first-contentful-paint") {
            console.log("time to first-contentful-paint is " + entry.startTime + " ms.", entry)
        }
        else if (entry.name == "first-paint") {
            console.log("time to first-paint is " + entry.startTime + " ms.", entry)
        }
    }
});

observer.observe({ entryTypes: ['paint'] });
```